# In the Rust function, what does the argument "||" do?

Tags: rust

In the Rust function, what does the argument "||" do?
What happens if it is not there?

Sample:

```
use std::sync::Once;
use core::panic::AssertUnwindSafe;

fn main() {
    let o = Once::new();
    let _ = std::panic::catch_unwind(AssertUnwindSafe(|| {
        o.call_once(|| panic!("foo"));
    }));
    o.call_once(|| {});
}
```

Comment: It's not an argument; it's syntax that changes the meaning of the `{...}` that follows. This is covered in [the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book) -- please do try to be familiar with the introductory docs before asking questions here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rust, [closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html) (or anonymous functions) use the syntax

```
|arg1, arg2, arg3, ...| body
```

For example, `|x| x * x` is a closure that takes a single argument and squares it:

```rust
let f = |x| x * x;
println!("{}", f(2)); // prints "4"
```

`||` (or `| |`) is just the syntax you get for a closure with no arguments:

```rust
let f = || 4;
println!("{}", f()); // prints "4"
```

If you remove `||` from this example, you get the value `4` in the variable `f` instead of a closure that returns `4`:

```rust
let f = 4;
println!("{}", f()); // error[E0618]: expected function, found `{integer}`
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
So this was the syntax for anonymous functions.
I understand now.